# Display element next to element with Flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

My div element with the class `user-list` is getting displayed below `.result` but it should be placed right next to it.

I tried it with `float: left` but it doesn't work. How can I do it with flex?

```css
.chat {
  position: relative;
  left: 10vw;
  height: 95vh;
  background-color: burlywood;
  width: 80vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.result {
  width: 80vw;
  height: 80vh;
  float: left;
  background: red;
}

.user-list {
    background-color: #F1F1F4;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat">

  <div class="result"></div>

  <div class="user-list">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia delectus, voluptatum ducimus ratione nemo dolor consequuntur maiores corrupti rerum architecto qui necessitatibus nulla, deserunt harum quaerat facere, eius et minus.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `flex-direction: row` instead of `flex-direction: column` on `.chat` element.